# Argument of '#selector' on constant in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

Just converted to Swift 4. On my project I have a warning that says the following

> Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'dismissKeyboard()'
>   in 'UIViewController' that depends on '@objc' inference deprecated in
>   Swift 4

for the following code

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(EntryViewController.dismissKeyboard))
```

My browsing of similar issues suggests adding @objc before the line, but Xcode then puts an error and the fix deletes it.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `@objc` not on the line that *calls* `dismissKeyboard`, but rather on the *declaration* of `func dismissKeyboard` itself, and you will solve your issue.